# What is the actual difference between MVC and MVC Model2

Tags: java, model-view-controller

just i want to know What is the actual difference between MVC and MVC Model2 in the development

Comment: I believe these 2 links contain the actual information you're trying to find out: [Model1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1), [Model2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2)

Comment: A good explaination can be found at <http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1999/jw-12-ssj-jspmvc.html>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To illustrate the previous answers (and add explanation from [this article](http://faq.javaranch.com/java/Model1Model2MVC)):

MVC2 is an [abuse of language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_language) referring actually to the JSP Model 2 architecture, as opposed to JSP Model 1:

> The first Java technology for server-side web development was the **servlet**.
>   Writing applications with servlets was very similar to writing CGI applications in Perl in that **all of the output had to be built up as Strings from within Java code**.
>   This was very tedious and error-prone. It also made it very difficult for web designers with no Java experience to alter the look and feel of the pages generated by servlets.

[image]
<sub>(source: [javaworld.com](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1999/images/MODEL1_sml.gif))</sub>

> Then came **JSP**. JSPs, like Microsoft ASPs and like the popular scripting language PHP, **treat everything as template text, but allow the insertion of Java code into tags called scriptlets and JSP expressions**.
>   This allowed people to work on server-side applications just as they would with the other popular scripting languages but it had a couple of drawbacks.
>
> - There was no separation of concerns.
> - One script would hold database code, business logic, HTML markup and any javascript code needed for the final page rendering.
> - Code reuse was difficult as was automated testing.
>
> This came to be known as "Model 1" JSP programming.
>
> [MVC or the Model View Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) was a common technique for separating the various concerns in GUI code invented by Trygve Reenskaug, working on Smalltalk for Zerox.
>
> At some point it became clear that this technique could be adapted to Java EE applications to achieve the same level of separation.
>   Doing so involves writing the Model layer as Beans or Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs), using servlets as the Controller, and then, when all the heavy lifting is done, forwarding to a JSP to format and markup the results.
>   Servlet/JSP applications written using and MVC architecture came to be known as Model 2 JSP programming.

[image]
<sub>(source: [javaworld.com](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1999/images/MODEL2_sml.gif))</sub>

> Because this pattern existed in a different form before being used in servlet/JSP applications, it was sometimes referred to as "MVC2". This name led to some confusion as it implied that there is an MVC1 for servlet applications, which there is not.
>   It is sufficient just to say MVC.

Comment: @VonC - Its not a good idea to copy without giving a reference. Please provide the reference in your original post. Thanks.

Comment: @Vinegar: it is not a good idea to comment without reading the answer ;) "and add explanation from **this article**": what is copied come from that article mentioned in the FIRST line.

Comment: So does that mean that MVC1 would be the event-driven MVC that you find in Swing and in the traditional Smalltalk GUI? (MVC2 doesn't need the observer because it's answering a web request whereas Swing and Smalltalk are both handling a desktop client... so they need callbacks on the model to trigger view refreshes)

Answer (score 3):

An amusing historical note on the terms...

[I wish I could find the paper... (I just tried googling but no luck!)]

A while back, someone wrote a paper describing two MVC approaches for web applications. In it, he had two figures.

The captions were "model 1" and "model 2".

They weren't intended as actual names of patterns (more like "figure 1" and "figure 2"), but someone read it and wrote about it as though that were a pattern name...

(anyone have the ref?)

VonC describes the difference pretty well

Comment: Interesting (+1). I merely copy and reformat and javaworld article, actually. Regarding your comment, this presentation ( http://www.javapassion.com/j2ee/MVCPatternAndFrameworks.pdf ) does mention "MVC model 1" and "MVC model 2"! (but that may be a by-product of your paper, and not the actual document you are refering to though)

Comment: Arf, in this "answer sheet" ( http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613s05/613s05FinalAnswerKey.pdf ), MVC Model “1” is oriented toward client-side applications, such as a Swing-based GUI
application. In this case all of the application code exists in a single JVM on a single client.
MVC Model “2” is oriented toward a client-server web application context, in which the user is issuing HTTP
requests to a server. In contrast to Model 1, the Model 2 architecture requires the implementation of a
single servlet which acts as the Controller and receives all requests from the client-side browsers.

Comment: That slide presentation is close, but it calls out Model 1/Model 2 as though they are actual terms... "Model 2" isn't really an evolutionary step as they say; it's just a different implementation of model/UI separation.

Comment: @VonC - Its not a good idea to copy without giving a reference. Please provide the reference in your original post. Thanks.

Comment: @Vinegar: I always provide the reference of what I put in my answers. Check out the first line of my post.

Comment: (although I admit it was not the "javaworld" article I did copy like I mentioned incorrectly in the first comment of Scott's answer, but the *faq.javaranch* one: that is the one referenced in the first line of my post)